# Height difficulties using bootstrap carousel slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While using the carousel slider i can display all content i want displayed. The problem is some of the content i'm displaying dosent fit the screen height-wise.
Link to example [Here](http://www.starv.fo/joboffers/slider)

My skills with javascript are quit limited. Was thinking if where was a way to solving this issue with plain css? or are other methods needed?

**My controller:**

```
public ActionResult Slider()
    {
        var valid = (from x in db.JobOffer
                     where x.JobStatusModelId == 1
                     orderby x.DateCreated descending
                     select new SliderViewModel()
                     {
                         JobOfferModelId = x.JobOfferModelId,
                         ContentId = x.ContentId,
                         JobTitle = x.JobTitle,
                         DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
                         DateVisible = x.DateUnvisible,
                         Content = x.Content


                     }).ToList();

        ViewBag.Slide = valid;


        return View();
    }
```

**My view**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div style="width: 70%; margin: auto;">
                <div style="background-color: white; margin-top: 0px; min-height: 1000px; border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;">

                    <div align="center">Leys størv á www.starv.fo</div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />

        </div>
    </div>



    @foreach (SliderViewModel item in ViewBag.Slide)
    {
        <div class="item">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="A4">
                    <div id="div">




                        <div style="background-color: white; margin-top: 0px;  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;">

                            <div class="oval">
                                <img src="/Heim/RetrieveImage/@item.ContentId" alt=""  height="60px;" /><br />
                            </div>
                            <div style="font-size: 25px; padding-left: 54px; padding-top: 45px;"><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitle)</b></div>


                            <div style="font-size: 16px; padding-left: 54px;">@Html.ShowCompany(item.ContentId.ToString())</div>
                            <div style="padding-top: 25px; font-size: 13px; padding-left: 54px; padding-right: 54px; line-height: 15px;">@Html.Raw(item.Content)<hr />
                            </div>


                        </div>

                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I know never use inline-style. But it is just a fast test site.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi there Qwerty**, for what I gather here you want to control the overall height of the carousel and try to display the varying heights of the info you display in the carousel.

This is what I did to do this to help here.

For the carousel I set the height to `max-height: 90vh;`.

Using `vh` like this the carousel is now responsive.

For your `class` of A4 I have this block `scroll`.
For the **main content** text body I gave this a height... you can set this to what suits you here.
This will stop the carousel from resizing when this area does not have much content.
You will need to go through your code and paste this `class="text-height"` into every div right below this
`<div style="font-size: 16px; padding-left: 54px;">Føroya Tele</div>`

I have only done this for the first 5 or 6 for this demo.

In the top of each section you had a set height of `height:1050px;` I removed all of these.

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/ddre7qex/)** of your carousel displaying all that content.

**[Full size Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/ddre7qex/embedded/result/)**

This code here sets the height of the carousel.

```
.carousel-inner  {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 90vh;

}
```

[image]

Comment: The height is the issue yes. The purpose of the slider is so a person can read the slider on a screen. But the issue is that the content dosent fit the screen. As you can see in your fiddle exampel.

Comment: Hi, so does this help you so far? I have given you a way to have very long content and very short content to show in a reasonable way.  If you want to you can set the height so the carousel looks ok... to only the height of the short content. Then a user will have to scroll a long way for the long content. An option for you to consider.  If not, you will need to give an example of what you actually want to do, so people can help.

Comment: Yes big help, thank you. Cant seem to find a working eksampel of what i want to accomplish. :/

But would a slow scroll pr page maybe a soulution to the problem?

Comment: Hi, Yes you probably need to look at how you want to user to use this. I took it that you set the scroll speed fast just to demo this. You do know that in my fiddle code on line **3236** you can change the carousel speed from **2000** to a larger number.